# (Done) How to deal with a pushy recruiter

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[How to deal with a recruiter who pushes me to attend an interview?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/118531/how-to-deal-with-a-recruiter-who-pushes-me-to-attend-an-interview)

This question has been edited to add an answerable question so the close reason doesn't apply anymore. It was edited when there were 3 close votes already. It still needs some love, though.

I recommend reopening because it's salvageable and the OP clearly needs some help.

Comment: I voted. It's done.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere (blows party horn)

Comment: Anyone who wants to re-open any question can feel free to ping me and I'll help. The more open questions the better, IMHO.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Done. This post needs at least 30 characters.